# Сброс сессии после перезапуска браузера

Tags: java, cookie

Есть тестовый код сервлета:

```
@WebServlet("/sessionS")
public class SessionReloadTest extends HttpServlet{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(0);
        Date date = (Date) session.getAttribute("date");
        if (date == null) {
                date = new Date();
                session.setAttribute("date", date);
        }
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("New Session? " + session.isNew());
        pw.println("Date : " + date);
        pw.flush();
    }
}
```

При первом обращении к серверу (`localhost:8090/WebAppTest/sessionS`) `session.isNew()` возвращает `true`. При последующих - `false`. Но после перезапуска браузера (firefox, IE, chrome mobile) у данного адреса нет куков (смотрел через настройки и плагин к firefox), и, соответственно, `isNew` возвращает снова true.

Настройки браузеров и томката стандартные, на других сайтах куки остаются.

Вопрос заключается в том, как сохранить куки после перезапуска, а так же почему они сбрасываются?

P.S. Наличие setMaxInactiveInterval(0) ничего не меняет

На всякий случай - Используется Tomcat 9.0.8

Comment: @AntonShchyrov добавил

Comment: Еще дело в том, что томкат по дефолту держит сессию в оперативной памяти (в хэш мапе), а если вы останавливаете сервер - соответственно теряются все данные. В настройках томката можно заменить рантайм сессию на ждбц.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сессия она на то и сессия, что живет до закрытия браузера. Если вам нужно больше - устанавливайте свои куки

```
boolean isNew = true;
Cookies[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if (cookies != null) {
  for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
    if (cookie.getName().equals("userExists")) {
      isNew = false;
      break;
    }
  }
}
Cookie exist = new Cookie("userExists", "1");
exist.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
response.addCookie(exist);

pw.println("New User? " + isNew);
```